# Why can't a single-level page table grow dynamically?

Tags: paging

I'm reading about page tables in Patterson & Hennessy's [*Computer Organization and Design RISC-V Edition*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0128122757). The excessive memory usage of a single-level page table is noted w/:

> with a single level page table for a 48-bit address with 4 KiB pages, we need 64 billion table entries. As each page table entry is 8 bytes for RISC-V, it would require 0.5 TiB

A number of memory-saving techniques are then introduced, such as a multi-level page table.

IIUC, the advantage of a multi-level table is that tables at higher levels don't need to be allocated at the start, only when the program addresses memory within a range corresponding to an entry in a lower-level table. Thus, it saves memory by delaying allocation of mappings.

Why can't a single-level table do the same? Is it necessary to allocate a mapping of every address from the start? Why can't the table hold only the mappings for the virtual addresses that the program is actually using and grow (or shrink) as needed?

Comment: Try thinking about that growing and shrinking data structure of yours. Don't forget that the pages need to be allocated and freed randomly.